# Use one application login to access another application built using AWS (both on same domain)

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, authentication

I am working on a web application part of which is running on our local server and part of the application is implemented using AWS. I am looking for a solution where if the user logs in to the using the part of application that is running on local side, the authentication and authorization is carried over to AWS and vice-versa.

Answer (score 0):

Check out AWS Cognito, specially User/Identity Pools.  You can do SSO and pass tokens from one app to another and authenticate against the Cognito endpoint in AWS.

Comment: would you mind explain a bit more? i'm having 2 react apps i need to automatically login if i login from one app. i have done upto setting up user pool and signin on one application